# php if to include html

Tags: php

PHP isn't really my language of choice, that being said I remember seeing a php `if` being used something like this:

```
<?php 
    if (blah) { 
?>
        // loads of html and js that doesn't need to be escaped since we closed
        // the php already with "?>"
<?php
    }
?>
```

Or something like this. I don't know what it's called and googling php if doesn't help.

What's this technique called and what's the correct syntax for it?

Comment: going in and out of php tags?

Comment: The correct syntax for it is as above. I call the technique "horrible". If you must do this, consider creating separate .html files and `include`ing them, mixing PHP and HTML creates an unreadable mess with sloppily white-spaced output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used as you posted in the question, or like this (which I prefer):

```
<?php 
    if(blah):
?>
        // loads of html and js that doesn't need to be escaped since we closed
        // the php already with "?>"
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

This is most often seen on templates where you don't do any logic, just simple `if` and `loops` like:

```
<?php foreach($something as $test): ?>
    <p><?php echo $test; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are called php tags. See here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

The syntax is as used in your example. There are variations, but the this one is preferable.

The other "technique" is called using control structures. See here:

http://ch.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this out:

[Can HTML be embedded inside PHP in IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722379/can-html-be-embedded-inside-php-if-stateme)

and

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is like this

```
<?php if ($test) : ?>
    <p>Some HTML</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is correct. There is also an alternative syntax which can improve readability of code if you have to mix PHP and HTML in places:

```
<?php if( blah ): ?>
  <!-- my HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I disagree with those who make the blanket statement for not mixing php and html. I use a templating system to separate application logic from HTML as much as possible, but there are still places where an `if` statement or `for` loop is needed within the template file.

Answer (score 1):

As another user pointed out, it's called Escaping from HTML, it's just an alternative to echo/print'ing out every line of HTML that is inside the PHP if statement.

That being said, the syntax you're using is just fine:

```
// Option 1
<?php if ($variable) { ?>
<!-- HTML stuff here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Or, the other way:

```
// Option 2
<?php
if ($variable) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<span>Totally putting HTML here</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Or, the third way as user1266222 pointed out:

```
// Option 3
<?php if ($variable) { include 'path/to/htmlfile/filename.html'; } ?>
```

Which would just include the HTML file there.

The method depends on what you wanna do, all are viable in all usecases, but for only very small snippets of HTML, I would go with option 2. For a whole HTML file (or even just partial), I would go with option 3. And if lazy and you have a longer piece of HTML, there is option 1.

Answer (score 1):

In the manual page it is called [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)
Of course, you can use whatever PHP statement with it, not only `if`

Correct syntax is one you used in your code snippet: use `?>` to close PHP mode and `<?php` to open it again, with the text between them directly going into browser

The usage of this technique have to be limited to PHP-based templates. Yet being **extremely useful** for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
<?php include("filename.html"); ?>
```

or you can just write html code if you are not inside of the php tags

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(blah){
include('htmlfile.html');
}
?>

htmlfile.html

<!-- Your HTML Code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called embedding PHP in HTML (or vice versa), there's an alternative syntax to make it look slightly better:

```
<?php if (condition) : ?>
HTML HTML HTML
<?php endIf; ?>
```

Using `include(file.html);` is usually a better way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a perfectly valid syntax, although doesn't look very pretty, so for files with lots of HTML you can also use:

```
<?php if($foo) : ?>
<p>Unescaped html goes here</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score -1):

You might consider the `heredoc`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc