# Why is this php If statement displaying html when condition is false

Tags: php, html, if-statement

Can someone please tell me why this php If-statement is displaying the html when the condition is false?

```
<?php if ($sidebar['blog_default_layout'] == "Left Sidebar") : ?>
    <aside class="sidebar span3" role="complementary">
        <?php get_sidebar( 'blog-sidebar' ); ?>
    </aside>
<?php endif ?>
```

According to: [Can HTML be embedded inside PHP “if” statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722379/can-html-be-embedded-inside-php-if-statement) this shouldn't display the html since the condition is not true.

The `<?php get_sidebar( 'blog-sidebar' ); ?>` between the html doesn't display, as it shouldn't.

Comment: What `var_dump($sidebar['blog_default_layout'])` shows?

Comment: It should definitely not display the HTML, which means that most likely the condition is indeed true.

Comment: are you sure the condition's false? What's the value in that var?

Comment: Your `if` statement is returning the html b/c it is true.

Comment: @raina77ow var_dump shows: string(13) "Right Sidebar"

Comment: var_dump($sidebar['blog_default_layout']); right before the condition?

Comment: ... or immediately after that `if` condition. ) But it's pointless actually: it's two strings, they will get compared as strings, so it should be `'Right Sidebar'` at this point. I wonder, though, what can change it. Is it Wordpress? Or some other blog engine?

Comment: You may want to dump that inside the if statement. B/c if it was false it would not execute.

Comment: @DanyCaissy I placed var_dump immediately before and immediately after...shows the same in both places.

Comment: Ok, we're doing basic debugging here at the moment... why don't you just check that the code DOES go into that `if`? Remove that 'aside' part, then place something really straight-forward - like `die(111)`, for example.

Comment: @raina77ow yes it is wordpress. I have another if-statement later on the page for Right Sidebar. That evaluates true and displays the html and the content as it should, but the Left Sidebar still displays html, but not the content inside. Left Sidebar should not display anything as it's false, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it: what do you mean by 'displays html'? Do you sse this `<aside class="sidebar span3" role="complementary">` in the resulting page's source code?

Comment: How do you know that the "displayed html" is the one corresponding to this code? I'm almost sure that you are seeing another piece of html, not this one. Have you tried changing a bit of this html (i.e. change the classes "sidebar span3"  to "sidebar span3 test") and checking if the change is reflected in what you see?

Also, can you please show us the full code of your script (even here or pasted somewhere else)?

Comment: @Racso Indeed. I think I have debugged this to being something outside of this if-statement. I believe the problem is related to another file.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I think I have this problems solved. It appears to be some leftover code in another file causing the issue. Stupid mistake on my part.