# PHP - Add string as html entities

Tags: php, html

```
$Header = 'test';
$Text = '<p class="test">Text></p><p class="test">Text></p>';

$message ='
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>'.$Header.'</title>

        </head>
        <body>';

        $message .='
        <p>'.$Header.'</p>
        <p></p>';
        $message .="$Text";

        $message .='
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
```

`echo $message;` outputs:

```
test
<p class="test">Text></p><p class="test">Text></p>
```

As we can see, the line `<p class="test">Text></p><p class="test">Text></p>` is displayed as string, not as an html entity.

How could I add `$Text` to `$message` variable so as I get it as an html entity  ?

P.S.: *the people I understand that for some, it is an easy question, but if You vote against it, please write the answer. many people do not know the answer to this question.*

Comment: i thing you are trying to embed html inside php, if so here is an easy way.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722379/can-html-be-embedded-inside-php-if-statement   ... hope it helps. thank you..

Comment: @user3234352 this answer not use `if else`

Comment: I think you are not showing origin of your message. Because `echo "<span style='color: red'>Red text</span>"` will print out `Red text` in red color as html

Answer (score -1):

You've almost given the answer yourself: use the function [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

```
$message .= htmlentities($Text);
```

It will translate `<`, `>` and a bunch of other characters to their respective HTML entities.

An alternative is [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). It also encodes the special characters of HTML (brackets and quotes), but not diacritics.

Comment: and it add `<p class="test">Text></p>` as `Text` ?

Comment: It should add `&lt;p class=&quote;test&quote;&gt;>Text&lt;/p&gt;`

Comment: @DamienPirsy i also see it - now on display we are see  `&lt;p class=&quot;strong&quot;&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt; ` `&lt;p class=&quot;strong&quot;&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt; `

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
$message .= $Text ;
```

instead of

```
$message .="$Text";
```

Comment: No. That doesn't make a difference, apart from being -theoretically- faster.