# Can HTML be embedded inside normal (i.e. not alternative) PHP if?

Tags: php, html

In [Can HTML be embedded inside PHP "if" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722379/can-html-be-embedded-inside-php-if-statement), the accepted (and most upvoted) answer mentions only the alternative if style.

The other 2 answers mention it works with normal if, as well, but is it standards-compliant, or is it non-standard but supported behavior?

I mean this code:

```
<?php if ($cond) { ?>
    If branch<br>
<?php } else { ?>
    Else branch<br>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: What standards are you referring to?

Comment: It's not a standard, but most appropriate way of writing this

Comment: @danronmoon Well, coming from C++, I was assuming there's a 1000 page PHP standard or something. But basically - are you supposed to do this, or only the alternative if should be used? By the way, that code works, I tested it on PHP5/Apache/chrome.

Comment: It's like how WordPress devs do that. See `wp-register.php` - that looks hard to read

Comment: No, you're not supposed to do this. By doing so, you make PHP code inside html-layots much easier to read and maintain

Comment: Summary: Yes, this is valid PHP syntax. This has always worked and there are no plans that I'm aware of to stop this.

Comment: The normal syntax is standard. The alternative syntax is non-standard. Some kids somehow are "lunatic" and favor the alternative syntax, however I never could feel with them. ^^

Comment: Just FYI: From a coding standard perspective, there is not so much in PHP for coding standards. The PSR-2 one says brackets are required for control structures, therefore the alternative syntax is not considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the standard syntax in PHP works.

As suggested by the term *standard* I used in my last sentence, I really meant that it is the standard syntax. It always worked. It will always work.

Consider the *alternative* syntax alternative, that is, non-standard. [The wording is from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), not from me personally.

Alterantive already suggests that it works exactly the same, so you can use any of those, despite the votes on some Q&A platform somewhere in the world wide web :)

---

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">This will only display if $condition is true</a>
<?php } ?>
```

By request, here's elseif and else (which you can also find in the docs: [elseif](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php); [else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php))

```
<?php if ($condition) { ?>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">This will only display if $condition is true</a>
<?php } elseif($anotherCondition) { ?>
    more html
<?php } else { ?>
    even more html
<?php } ?>
```

It's that simple.

The HTML will only be displayed if the condition is satisfied.

---

I hope this exemplary reqplique does add enough clarity if there were any doubts.