# How to add html inside an if else statement in php?

Tags: php, html

I have this code where if something then display a link, else display another link. the if and else are php code, and the links are html as you will know, but I was wondering how do you make it so it will not give me any errors, how do I combine php with html?

```
  <?php foreach ($user_socs as $user_soc) { 
  if ($soca == $user_soc) {

  <a href="file.php" class="socbuttons">Leave Society</a>;

  } else {
  <a href="anotherfile.php" class="socbuttons">Join Society</a>;

  }
```

Comment: seems like a duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722379/can-html-be-embedded-inside-php-if-statement

Comment: `<?php logic?>`html logic`<?php logic?>`html logic`<?php logic?>`

Comment: This tutorial might help: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php

Answer (score 1):

This might help you. This one is from the basics of PHP:

```
<?php foreach ($user_socs as $user_soc) { 
     if ($soca == $user_soc) { 
         echo "<a href='file.php' class='socbuttons'>Leave Society</a>";
     } else { 
         echo "<a href='anotherfile.php' class='socbuttons'>Join Society</a>";
     }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember PHP should be surrounded by `<?php` `?>`. Simply end the "PHP part" and then start it again when you finished your HTML.

```
      <?php foreach ($user_socs as $user_soc) { 

      if ($soca == $user_soc) {

      ?> <a href="file.php" class="socbuttons">Leave Society</a> <?

      } else {
      ?> <a href="anotherfile.php" class="socbuttons">Join Society</a><?

      }
```

Also, you can write HTML in `echo` statement, but you should escape some special characters like `"` to not interfere with the php code itself.

```
      <?php foreach ($user_socs as $user_soc) { 

      if ($soca == $user_soc) {

      echo "<a href=\"file.php\" class=\"socbuttons\">Leave Society</a>";

      } else {
      echo "<a href=\"anotherfile.php\" class=\"socbuttons\">Join Society</a>";

      }
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php to more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ($user_socs as $user_soc) { 
      if ($soca == $user_soc) { ?>

      <a href="file.php" class="socbuttons">Leave Society</a>;

 <?php          } else { ?>
      <a href="anotherfile.php" class="socbuttons">Join Society</a>;

      <?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alternate syntax:

```
<?php
      $aUserSocs = array( 'link1', 'link2', 'link3' );
      $soca = 'link2';
      $iCountUserSocs = count( $aUserSocs );
      for( $i = 0; $i < $iCountUserSocs; ++$i ):
?>
        <?php if( $soca == $aUserSocs[ $i ] ): ?>
            <a href="file.php" class="socbuttons">Leave Society</a>;
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="anotherfile.php" class="socbuttons">Join Society</a>;
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Alternate syntax requires closures for loops and conditionals. Else and elseifs can be placed inside if statements so long as they use :