# How to echo lots of HTML between an IF statement

Tags: php

At the moment my PHP code is like this:

```
<?php
some code
?>

lots of HTML

<?php
some more code
?>
```

I now want to include large chunks of HTML depending upon the values of certain PHP variables so like this:

```
<?php
if ($requiresSignature===true) {
 echo "some HTML";
 echo "some more HTML";
}
?>
```

Using `echo` is fine for a few lines of HTML but is there an easier way when I've got maybe 500 lines of HTML so I don't have to type `echo` in front of each line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML be embedded inside PHP "if" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722379/can-html-be-embedded-inside-php-if-statement)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way

```
<?php
if ($requiresSignature===true) {
?>
 <b>some HTML</b>
 <b>some more HTML</b>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I didn't realise you could do that - perfect!

Comment: @AndyGroom Since you find this to be the correct answer, it'd be Humane to go ahead & mark it as the right solution. There are 2 main reasons for this: 1.) It motivates the Contributor to keep up the good works: thus it is like buying the Contributor a Beer (if you will). 2.) It is an indicator to any visitor that this is the Solution that solved your problem because they'd see the green Check-mark that says: This solved my Problem. However; it is not mandatory - just a show of goodwill - considering that the contributor invested time & mental energy to help out, plus it costs you nothing ;-)

Comment: haha you're right but maybe he forgot.. lets wait and see haha :)

Answer (score 1):

For this usage, the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) functionalities of php are the best options, in my humble opinion.

### Heredoc

`Heredoc` is like `echo "Foo bar";` but intended for a large chunk of text, spanning multiple lines.

Like this:

```
echo <<<FOO
    <h1>Foo bar</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit tenet conseqteur...</p>
    <i>Created by $name</i>
FOO;
```

This syntax is also available for setting variables, class properties, class constants and static variables (since php 5.3). The `FOO` part, you can set yourself. Just remember to close the `Heredoc` with the same ending on a line by itself (with **absolutely no indentation**), ended with a semicolon.

E.g.

```
$foo = <<<BAR
    This is an example text.
    Spanning multiple lines.
BAR;
```

### Nowdoc

Think of Nowdoc as the `'` equivalent of `"`. That is, no variable substitution is performed inside a Nowdoc statement, just like none is performed inside a `'single quoted string'`.

The syntax is like this:

```
echo <<<'EXAMPLE'
    This

    is
    a
    test
EXAMPLE;
```

In conclusion I would do like this:

```
if ($requiresSignature===true) {
    echo <<<HTML
    Some html<br/>
    And even more <b class="html">html</b>
HTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

```
<?php
$Html = "";
if ($requiresSignature===true) {
 $Html .="some HTML";
 $Html .="some more HTML";

 echo $Html;
}
?>
```

Comment: It will throw Undefined variable: Html

Comment: @RajkumarR Answer edited. put some default value to $Html

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '
    some html
    some html
    some html
';
```

I think that's what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if (true){
  ?>

pure html code here

<?php

else{

?>

pure html code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $Html = '';
    if ($requiresSignature===true) {
        $Html .="some HTML";
        $Html .="some more HTML";
        echo $Html;
    }  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use heredoc syntax: See more detail in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
echo <<<"MYHTML"
html
lots of html
MYHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for you

```
 <?php if( var == true ): ?>

 <p>Your HTML</p> 

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

variables output in the plain HTML, consider doing so like this:

```
<?= $variable ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's useful, try this code:

```
<?php
   if ($requiresSignature===true) {
      $var = "some HTML";
      $var .=  "some more HTML";
      echo $var;
}
?>

**OR**

<?php if ($requiresSignature===true) { ?>

HTML CODE

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Don' Need to write echo to each line.

You Should use :

```
echo '
    some html
    some more html
    some more html
';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a HTML embed language.You can try it every where of your php page.

```
<?php if ($requiresSignature===true): ?>
<p>"some more HTML"</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*...but is there an easier way when I've got maybe 500 lines of HTML so I don't have to type echo in front of each line?* It turns out there is, so **yes** and here is how:

```
    <?php
        $myString  = "PHP is so cool...";
        if($requiredSignature === true): 
    ?>
    <div class='too-much-html-markup'>
        All the RAW HTML MARKUP here would only be displayed if (and only if) 
        the condition above evaluates to true so i don't have to worry about 
        any kind of echoing. However, i can still go ahead and echo some
        content here if i still choose like this: <?php echo $myString; ?>
        And everything will still work out just fine.
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
    <div class='still-some-raw-html-in-else-clause'>
        Again this is a raw Markup and will only be rendered if the IF 
        condition above evaluates to FALSE!
    </div>
    <?php endif; //<== NOW I END THE CONDITIONAL LOGIC WITH endif KEYWORD ?>
```