# Why is my PHP IF/Else printing all options

Tags: php, html

I have this html code using PHP and when i run it i get both responces. What am i doing wrong

[image: Here is the HTML/PHP]

[This is the Output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfo3k.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Hello User </h1>

<?php 
$a = 4;
$b = 4; 

if ($a==$b): ?>

<h2> True </h2>

<?php else: ?>

<h2> False </h2>

<?php endif ?>

</body>
</html>

~~~~~
```

Comment: Please add code as text, not an image, so it can be easily copied by anyone.

Comment: Duplicated question, Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/722395/2123606

Comment: @YehiaElhawary I disagree, OP is using that exact syntax. I cannot reproduce this with the code shown, problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: pls, show the output result

Comment: Thank you very much but why does this workand mine above not?

Comment: We can't know unless you give us more information. Is this code or output that you have attached? What you wrote should work. Please edit the question to add more information.

Comment: If you get some strange result, show it to us. However, there's nothing wrong with the posted code.

Comment: @YehiaElhawary - How does that answer the OP's question when the answer suggest doing what the OP already does?

Comment: @Dlk - The only logical diff between your comment and the OP's code is two vs three equal signs, which shouldn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: Updated to show my output

Comment: Can you add the source code as text rather than an image.

Comment: Check the page source (right click > view source) and see if you can see the PHP code as well. Btw, how are you running this file? Through a web server or are you opening the php-file directly in your browser from the file system?

Comment: Eventually I wanted to run this in a Flask extension but at the moment im saving it as a HTML page and running it using chrome

Comment: Browsers can't run PHP code on their own. You can use [PHP''s built in web server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) while you're developing on your local machine.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Nvm as you said posted code is correct, probably OP forgot to start php server or .php extension.

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote works fine. The problem is that the PHP code is not getting executed. Make sure that it is running locally and the file extension is `.php` since your output is similar to the case of `.html` file with the same code.

Comment: Spot on. I expected the output to contain displayed php code.

Comment: _"Make sure that it is running locally"_ - That what is running locally?